# Calling functions and getting error that it's not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am in my 2nd JavaScript class and we have not learned the bebugging tools yet, I look at errors that are thrown in the browser. I have the following code (it includes Data Validation):

```
/**
* displayFunction gets info from form and displays message on screen
* it also called all the validation functions for the form
*/

function displayInfo() {
    //declare variables and initialize them.
    var fullName = document.myForm.fullName.value;
    var int1 = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["int1"].value);
    var int2 = parseInt(document.myForm.int2.value);
    var num3 = parseInt(document.myForm.num3.value);
    var num4 = parseInt(document.myForm.num4.value);
    var num5 = parseInt(document.myForm.num5.value);

    //make sure variable flag = 0
    flag = 0;
    //call the Validation functions
    nameValidate(fullName);
    int1Validate(int1);
    int2Validate(int2);
    num3Validate(num3);
    num4Validate(num4);
    num5Validate(num5);

    //call tha functions to find largest and smallest numbers and the sum
    var largest = largest(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
    var smallest = smallest(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
    var sum = sum(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);

    //Display the outpu t it everything is entered right.
    if (flag == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Hello, " + fullName + ". You entered: " + int1 + ", " + int2 + ", " + num3 +
        ", " + num4 + ", " + num5 + ". The largest number entered was " + largest + ". The smallest number you entered was " + smallest + 
        ". And the sum of all of the numbers was " + sum + ".";
    }
}
```

I am trying to take the numbers from a form and then find the largest number, the smallest number and the sum. I have made separate functions for these and they are called in the code above, but clearly I am missing some huge thing because the inspect window in the browser is throwing the error that "largest" "smallest" and "sum" are not functions. They're in the code. I am trying to do this with an allergy headache and am missing something really small, I hope someone can spot what I am missing.

Here is the largest function, the other two are practically the same:

```
/**
* largest takes in the numbers and returns the largest number
* @params - 5 ints
* @return - largest number
*/

//declare function largest and take in int1, int2, num3, num4, and num5
function largest (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) {
    //declare variable largest and use Math.max to find the largest number
    var largest = Math.max(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);

    return largest;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error message?  It just helps with finding a solution ^^

Comment: I would have thought I could just call the function and use what was returned for the text output, but what was displayed was the full function and not the result.

Comment: assignment2.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: largest is not a function
    at displayInfo (assignment2.js:31)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (dataValidation.html:31)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using the same variable name for your result as for the function you're calling. `var` gets hoisted to the top of its function, so to the interpreter, your code *actually* looks like this:

```
function displayInfo() {
  var largest;
  var smallest;
  var sum;
  // ...
  largest = largest(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
  smallest = smallest(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
  sum = sum(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
```

The interpreter will assume you're referring to the variable named `largest` *closest to the current scope* - which in this case is a variable named `largest` that has not been defined yet. Eg

```js
function largest() {
}
function doSomething() {
  console.log(typeof largest);
  var largest = largest();
}
doSomething();
```

Use different variable names for your results instead:

```
var largestResult = largest(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
var smallestResult = smallest(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
var sumResult = sum(int1, int2, num3, num4, num5);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's hard to think with a headache and a stuffed up nose